# Merge Sort string array by length

Tags: c++, sorting, mergesort

I'm attempting to sort an extremely large set of strings read in from a .txt and sort them. So far I'm probably able to sort them by alphabetical orders, but I cannot figure out how to sort them by length first then sort them alphabetically. Here is my code so far, hope someone shed some light on it. Thanks!

```
int lower = 0; 
int upper = sizeof(dataSetForSort) - 1;
int middle = (lower + upper)/2;
string Temp[sizeof(dataSetForSort)];


int i = lower, j = middle + 1 , k = lower;

while(i <= middle && j <= upper)
{
    if( dataSetForSort[i] < dataSetForSort[j] )
    {
        Temp[k].assign(dataSetForSort[i]);
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        Temp[k].assign(dataSetForSort[j]);
        j++;
    }
    k++;
}
if(i > middle )
{
    for(int h = j ;h <= upper ; h++ )
    {
        Temp[k].assign(dataSetForSort[h]);
        k++;
    }
}
else
    for(int h = i; h<= middle ; h++ )
    {
        Temp[k].assign(dataSetForSort[h]);
        k++;
    }
    for(int i = lower; i <= upper ; i++)
    {
       dataSetForSort[i].assign(Temp[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your comparison you can change to the following in order to sort by length first, and if lengths are equal, sort alphabetically:

```
if( dataSetForSort[i].size() < dataSetForSort[j].size() ||
    (dataSetForSort[i].size() == dataSetForSort[j].size() && 
    dataSetForSort[i] < dataSetForSort[j]) )
```

Comment: Do I need to create a string minValue so that I can compare it with the element  and swap? I still don't quite get the actual process of merge sorting them by length...EDIT: wait I kinda started to get what you are saying now but still need some explanation though...

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `minValue` string, but for the code you have shown it doesn't seem needed. Explanation of merge sort is a separate question, you can try reading this here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a `lessthan` function which returns the correct comparison.

```
bool lessthan( const std::string & left_hand_side, const std::string &   right_hand_side )
{
     // sort by length
     if( left_hand_side.length() < right_hand_side.length() ) return true;
     if( left_hand_side.length() > right_hand_side.length() ) return false;
     // sort by alphabet
     if( left_hand_side < right_hand_side ) return true;
     if( left_hand_side > right_hand_side ) return false;

     return false;
}
```

this can be used by std::sort, or made into an operator for your requirements